# How to include months of next year in JQuery UI DatePicker month selector (rolling 12 next months)

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

is it possible to have "rolling next 12 months" (including months in next year) in JQuery UI DatePicker's month dropdown selector?

For example, at the moment (Oct 2012) I'd like to have the following months:

- Oct 2012 (current year)
- Nov 2012 ...
- Dec 2012 (current year)
- Jan 2013 (next year)
- Feb 2013 ...
- ...
- Sep 2013 (next year)

With maxDate etc I can have months from this month to end of current year. And with changeYear I can enable year selector. But is it possible to set up month selector as described?

br, Touko